# Можно ли слить две строки в одну сохраняя порядок символов?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Программа проверяет можно ли сформировать заданную строку *S* из двух других строк *P<sub>1</sub>* и *P<sub>2</sub>* так, чтобы не осталось лишних символов.

Символы в *P<sub>1</sub>* и *P<sub>2</sub>* должны быть в том же порядке, что и в *S*.

Пример:

`radency` можно сформировать с помощью `rdnc` и `aey`:

> ```
> S  : r a d e n c y = radency
> P_1: r   d   n c   = rdnc
> P_2:   a   e     y = aey
> ```

Попытка решения:

```
const stringChecker = function (s, p1, p2) {
  let result = p1 + p2;
  const a = result.split('').sort().join('');
  const b = s.split('').sort().join('');
    
  return a === b;
};
```

Comment: Я отредактировал ваш вопрос. Если вы не согласны, верните предыдущую версию из истории. Или напишите тут, я верну.

Answer (score 2):

Решение за экспоненту - буквальное кодирование задачи:

```js
const stringChecker = (s, p1, p2) => {
    const search = (i, j) => 
        (i + j === s.length) ||
        (p1[i] === s[i + j] && search(i + 1, j)) ||
        (p2[j] === s[i + j] && search(i, j + 1))
    ;
    return s.length === p1.length + p2.length && search(0, 0);
};

console.log(stringChecker('radency', 'rdnc', 'aey'));
console.log(stringChecker('radency', 'rdnd', 'aey'));
```

Решение за квадрат по времени и по памяти. Вопрос - можно ли быстрее?

```js
const stringChecker = (s, p1, p2) => {
    const cache = [];
    const search = (i, j) => {
        if (cache[i] === undefined) {
            cache[i] = [];
        }
        if (cache[i][j] === undefined) {
            cache[i][j] = (
                (i + j === s.length) ||
                (p1[i] === s[i + j] && search(i + 1, j)) ||
                (p2[j] === s[i + j] && search(i, j + 1))
            );
        }
        return cache[i][j];
    };

    return s.length === p1.length + p2.length && search(0, 0);
};

console.log(stringChecker('radency', 'rdnc', 'aey'));
console.log(stringChecker('radency', 'rdnd', 'aey'));
```

Comment: зачем тут вообще рекурсивные решения?

Comment: Жадный алгоритм я не сумел придумать. Вот пример: `raroraro`, `roro`, `rara`. Всякий раз когда натыкаешься на `r` надо выбирать из какой строки его взять. А (не)правильность этого выбора становится ясна только позже. Другими словами, без поиска с возвратом не обойтись.